# Replace all regex occurrences with item from array by index from regex group

Tags: regex, kotlin, regex-group

I have text:

`Lorem ipsum %NAME0% dolor sit amet %NAME1%, consectetur %NAME2% adipiscing elit.`

and array `names`:
`[Bob, Alice, Tom]`

I need to get `X` index from `%NAMEX%` and replace all `%NAME0%`, `%NAME1%`, `%NAME2%` with corresponding item from array: `names.get(X)`.

I have

```
private fun String.replaceWithNames(names: List<String>): String {
    var result = this
    names.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
        result = result.replace("%NAME$index%", s)
    }
    return result
}
```

but I am sure that it can be done more optimally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regex to go through the string only once and replace each value using the last [Regex.replace](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html) overload (with lambda). Also, I added some validation in case there is a name reference with an out of bounds index (your current code would just leave the reference there).

```kotlin
private val nameRefRegex = Regex("""%NAME(\d)%""")

private fun String.replaceWithNames(names: List<String>): String {
    return nameRefRegex.replace(this) { match ->
        val index = match.groupValues[1].toInt()
        require(index in names.indices) { "Invalid name index $index, only ${names.size} names available" }
        names[index]
    }
}
```

Note: if you need more than 10 names, you could change `(\d)` to `(\d+)` in the regex (to support more than 1 digit)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following based on the [`kotlin.text.replace`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html) function:

```kotlin
val pattern = """%NAME(\d+)%""".toRegex()
fun String.replaceWithNames(names: List<String>): String {
    return this.replace(pattern, fun(m: MatchResult) : String { 
        return names.getOrNull(m.groupValues[1].toInt()) ?: m.value
    })
}
```

Or,

```kotlin
val pattern = """%NAME(\d+)%""".toRegex()
fun String.replaceWithNames(names: List<String>): String {
    return pattern.replace(this) { m ->
        names.getOrNull(m.groupValues[1].toInt()) ?: m.value
    }
}
```

See the [online Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/LhPe3b):

```kotlin
import java.util.*
 
val pattern = """%NAME(\d+)%""".toRegex()
fun String.replaceWithNames(names: List<String>): String {
    return pattern.replace(this) { m ->
        names.getOrNull(m.groupValues[1].toInt()) ?: m.value
    }
}
 
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val lst = listOf("Bob", "Alice", "Tom")
    println( "Lorem ipsum %NAME0% dolor sit amet %NAME1%, consectetur %NAME2% adipiscing elit. Wrong %NAME11%".replaceWithNames(lst) )
}
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum Bob dolor sit amet Alice, consectetur Tom adipiscing elit. Wrong %NAME11%
```

The `%NAME(\d+)%` regex matches `%NAME`, then captures one or more digits into Group 1, and then matches a `%` char.

If names contains the index captured in Group 1, the replacement is the corresponding `names` item, else, it is the whole match.